# HostNotFound: error when connecting to MongoDB pod in same namespace

Tags: mongodb, bitnami

I am trying to connect to a MongoDB pod (**mongodb-deployment-c896cf876-djhvl**)  from another MongoDB pod (**mongodb-0**) which is in the same namespace but when I attempt to do so I am getting an error :

```
kubectl exec -it mongodb-0 -- sh

mongo mongodb://admin:abc123@mongodb-headless-service.svc.cluster.local/platforms?`authSource=admin MongoDB shell version v5.0.9 connecting to: mongodb://mongodb-headless-service.svc.cluster.local:27017/platforms?authSource=admin&compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb Error: couldn't connect to server mongodb-headless-service.svc.cluster.local:27017, connection attempt failed: HostNotFound: Could not find address for mongodb-headless-service.svc.cluster.local:27017: SocketException: Host not found (authoritative) : connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:372:17 @(connect):2:6 exception: connect failed exiting with code 1`
```

When I test the connection in the original pod it authenticates successfully :

```
kubectl exec -it mongodb-deployment-c896cf876-djhvl -- sh

mongo "mongodb://admin:abc123@localhost/platforms?authSource=admin"
MongoDB shell version v4.4.6
connecting to: mongodb://localhost:27017/platforms?authSource=admin&compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("23c1e0ce-3369-4449-8895-1a6791246b67") }
MongoDB server version: 4.4.6
---
....
....
```

I have tried specifying namespace but still I get same error :

```
mongo mongodb://admin:abc123@mongodb-headless-service.labs.svc.cluster.local/platforms?authSource=admin
```

I have checked with kubectl describe deployment *whether bind-ip is specified* (*is this even necessary ?*) and I observe its not configured.
I have reconfigured the deployment to specify bind-ips as below:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongodb-deployment
  namespace: labs
  labels:
    app: mongodb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongodb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongodb
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mongodb
        image: docker.io/bitnami/mongodb:4.4.6-debian-10-r0
        imagePullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
        command:
          - "mongod"
          - "--bind_ip"
          - "0.0.0.0"
        securityContext:
            runAsNonRoot: true
            runAsUser: 1001
        ports:
          - containerPort: 27017
        env:
            - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mongodb-secret-amended
                  key: mongo-root-username
            - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mongodb-secret-amended
                  key: mongo-root-password
        volumeMounts: 
            - mountPath: /data/db
              name: mongodb-vol
      volumes:
      - name: mongodb-vol
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mongodb-claim
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongodb-headless-service
  namespace: labs
spec:
  selector:
    app: mongodb
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
```

Persistent Volume Claim

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mongodb-claim
  namespace: labs
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 200Mi
```

And I created a user in mongodb-deployment-c896cf876-djhvl using :

```
db.createUser({ user: "root", pwd: "abc123", roles: [ { role: "root", db: "admin" } ],mechanisms:["SCRAM-SHA-1"]})
```

After adding bind-ips I also get an error on container startup :

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-06-12T10:23:14.337+00:00"},"s":"I",  

"c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-06-12T10:23:14.339+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-06-12T10:23:14.339+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-06-12T10:23:14.340+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":1,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"mongodb-deployment-c896cf876-djhvl"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-06-12T10:23:14.340+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.6","gitVersion":"72e66213c2c3eab37d9358d5e78ad7f5c1d0d0d7","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"debian10","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-06-12T10:23:14.340+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"PRETTY_NAME=\"Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)\"","version":"Kernel 5.8.0-43-generic"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-06-12T10:23:14.340+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"net":{"bindIp":"0.0.0.0"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-06-12T10:23:14.341+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20557,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"DBException in initAndListen, terminating","attr":{"error":"IllegalOperation: Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /data/db"}}
```

I am convinced my issue is not about bind-ips really though. *As it is I cannot assign bind-ips , those permissions are not there, Bitnami Mongo images run as non-root by default and overriding is not possible*.

Is it not that the containers should discover each other by default (They are already in same namespace and I have used the recommended Mongo-URI pattern).

What am I missing ?

Comment: Reading helps: `Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /data/db`

Comment: Also, please provide an [mcve] -- the persistent volume claim is lacking.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Added PVC. The connecting pod mongodb-0 can be any mongo container (non Bitnami) no need for the manifests

Comment: You should also adjust the envs for username and password to be static. Remember, making it easy to replicate your problem makes it much easier to answer your question and thus more likely to get a useful answer.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg you can hardcode username and password for now and then remove the reference to the secret.